# Save JSON string in dynamic global dictionary , python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, global-variables, store

I am new to python. I have multiple JSON messages coming to the python application trough MQTT broker with the same keys but different values. what I am trying to do is to store the JSON string on a dynamic global dictionary according to a certain value and it will be replaced with each new messages has that same value.
then I can reach these values from any functions.

for example: if I have the following message

```
{'timestamp': 1646682501888, 'description': 'address', 'postal': 'AAA', 'city': 'ABC'}
```

I want to save a record of this message when city is ABC and postal is AAA in the first record, and if the city is "EFG" and postal is "ZZZ" store it in a second record,
than whenever a new message is coming it will update the full message if it has the same city and postal. please I want to know how to access values in the dictionary from any function.
thanks

Comment: No code is provided so it would be difficult to start helping. A few lines of code provide more information than many more words. An import of the appropriate standard library used with JSON would give useful information. A dictionary data structure named and created etc.

Comment: Use a tuple`(city, postal)` as the dictionary key. Then you can do `d[(new_record['city'], new_record['postal'])] = new_record`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might consider whether you would be better served by using a database, so it can be saved to disk.

Comment: Please supply an example of a query to the dictionry. I.e. are you going to search a city, postal code, eyc.